# How can I add some sort of highlight like animation in python over a typewriter animation?

Tags: python, string, animation

I have written this function for a project where I need a welcome message:

```
import os
import sys
import time

message = "Helllo! \n\
We're glad to have your here! \n\
How may I assist you? \n\
"

def typewriter(message):
  for char in message:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
    if char != "\n" :
      time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
      time.sleep(1)

os.system("clear")
```

If I wanted to add a white highlight covering each character for 0.1 seconds 3 times going a full lap how may I do it?

Right now I haven't been able to think of a way to solve this since I'm new to coding.

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI codes to set the background (looks like highlights) and text color:

```
sys.stdout.write('\033[47m') # makes the background white (47)
sys.stdout.write('\033[30m') # makes the text white (30)
sys.stdout.write('\033[0m') # back to default style
```

Write those before the `sys.stdout.write(char)` to let them be applied.

Use `'\b'` to move the cursor back one step, in order to overwrite the highlighted character that was just written with a character in default style, then overwrite it with highlighted style again (in a loop) in order to obtain the flashing effect. You were already using the sleep function so the effect won't be too fast to see.

You can combine the \b and style codes in one line like this: `sys.stdout.write('\b\033[47m\033[30m')`

There are three l's in your helllo ; )

Putting that together makes:

```
import os
import sys
import time

def typewriter(message):
    for char in message:
        
        sys.stdout.write('\033[0m')  # reset style to default
        sys.stdout.write(char) # print char with default style
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if char not in ['\n', ' ']:  
            for _ in range(3):
                sys.stdout.write('\b\033[47m\033[30m')  # move cursor back one space + highlight style
                sys.stdout.write(char)  # print char with highlight
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.05)  # short pause to show the char with highlight

                sys.stdout.write('\b\033[0m')  # move cursor back + reset style to default
                sys.stdout.write(char)  # print char with default style
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.1)  # pause before highlighting again

        else:
            if char == "\n":
                time.sleep(0.9)  # longer pause at new lines

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # clear terminal screen before starting 

message = "Hello! \n" \
"We're glad to have you here! \n" \
"How may I assist you? \n"

typewriter(message) # execute the function
```